# count of records grouped per userId

Tags: mongodb

This mongo command is expected to group the documents by userId and give the count of documents for each userId, but it is giving only the total count. How can it fix it?  thx
`{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }`

Comment: Try `{ $group: { _id: "$userId", count: { $sum: 1 } } }`

Comment: Thx. that worked.